# Issue rendering Switch in Android

Tags: android, android-switch, switchcompat

I am trying to use Switch component of Android but while clicking on it, I am getting below view which is not desired, it is showing 2 states at a time (checked as well as unchecked).

I also used custom style but getting no success. Below is my custom style. I have used the same view in a fragment, there I am facing no issue, but in another activity I am getting this issue. Can anyone suggest what the problem might be? I have used all variations like Switch, SwitchMaterial, SwitchCompat but same issue is occuring.

```
<style name="Switch_Veg_Only" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>

    <!-- inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/grey
    </item>

    <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f
    </item>
</style>
```

Below is the Switch xml file:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/activity_filter_switch_veg_only"
        android:theme="@style/Switch_Veg_Only"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/activity_filter_text_view_filter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/activity_filter_text_view_filter"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/fragment_home_veg_only"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textOn="a"
        android:textOff="b"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fragment_home_veg_only"
        app:switchPadding="8dp" />
```

[image: Output image]